# How to get attribute value from root with xPathNavigator

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I try to get the type of the pain from the xmlns attribute like this:

```
XPathNavigator pymntsTypeNode = 
mPymntsNavigator.SelectSingleNode("Document");
        bool success = pymntsTypeNode.MoveToFirstAttribute();

        if (success)
        {
            if (pymntsTypeNode.Value.Contains("pain.001") || pymntsTypeNode.Value.Contains("pain.008"))
            {
                return pymntsTypeNode.Value;
            }
            throw new Exception("invalid attribute of payment type");
        }
```

from this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
<GrpHdr>
...
...
...
```

Comment: What you have is a namespace, not an attribute.  Namespace have the same format as attributes but are not intended to be used for parameter data.

Comment: Thanks, but I stiil have to get a data from this Namespace. In the first line pymntsTypeNode is null because 'SelectSingleNode' can't return anything when the first Tag contains a Namespace

Comment: Then add the namespace to your parser.  See msdn example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tywd160x(v=vs.110).aspx